# Разница между двоеточием и тире (на конкретных примерах)

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Давно хотел понять разницу между двоеточием и тире. Даю примеры.

1. Цель исследования: изучение основных высших психических функций.
2. У испытуемого наблюдались многочисленные ошибки, при составлении самостоятельного рассказа — однообразие и бедность речевых конструкций.

Когда нужно ставить двоеточие, а когда — тире? Правильно ли я поставил их в этих предложениях?

Answer (score 5):

Если рассматривать конкретно данные Вами предложения, то в них пунктуация соблюдена верно **с точки зрения постановки тире и двоеточия. Однако в одном предложении не хватает запятой :-) Разберём по порядку:

“**Цель исследований**: сделать что-либо“.

Двоеточие в данной конструкции объясняется научно-деловым стилем оформления данной работы. Так, например, подобные записи очень часто можно увидеть в определённых отчётах либо исследованиях. Достаточно вспомнить оформление лабораторной работы по физике:

•Тема: ...

1. Цель: ...;
2. Оборудование: ...;
3. Ход работы: ...;
4. Вывод: ...;

Отмечу, что наш пример как раз является ярким примером приведённого выше шаблона. В художественном же стиле более уместным, даже нормативным, является постановка тире на основании наличия грамматической связи вида “подлежащее—сказуемое“. Чтобы Вы поняли, разберу на уже использованном примере:

“Цель исследований — изучение...“

Здесь “цель“ — подлежащее в **им.п.**, а “изучение“ — сказуемое **в том же падеже**.

“Наблюдались многочисленные ошибки,**при составлении самостоятельного рассказа**, — однообразие и бедность речевых конструкций“.

Выделенная часть является обособленным обстоятельством со значением уступки (где Вы и забыли постаивать запятую), поэтому для удобства уберём её, преобразовав предложение следующим образом:

“Наблюдались многочисленные ошибки — однообразие и бедность речевых конструкций“.

Тире в данном случае ставится на основании уточняющего оборота, однако в то же время имеет несколько авторское значение. Так что можно было просто поставить запятую.

За дополнительными сведениями насчёт постановки тире и двоеточия обратитесь на портал “Грамота.ру“ по следующим ссылкам:

http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire;

http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/157-dvoe