# Двоеточие-то или тире-с?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно? Оба варианта?

> Мои цели на 2024-й — найти по-немецки и -французски говорящих друзей, подарить Арине — Шерон подсолнечник и найти кота.

> Мои цели на 2024-й: найти по-немецки и -французски говорящих друзей, подарить Арине — Шерон подсолнечник и найти кота.

Comment: Меня, пожалуйста, через дефис пишите.  А своему другу Георгу подарите отсолнечник.

Comment: Почему через дефис? Я задавал этот вопрос. *Арина-Шерон* — не вы.

Comment: Конечно, не я.  У профиля Шерон могут быть и другие имена. А что же вам никто не ответил? Не знают-с?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Мои цели на 2024-й — найти по-немецки и -французски говорящих друзей, подарить Арине — Шерон подсолнечник и найти кота* — *цели* — подлежащее; *найти, подарить, найти* — сказуемые.

*Мои цели на 2024-й: найти по-немецки и -французски говорящих друзей, подарить Арине — Шерон подсолнечник и найти кота* —двоеточие подчëркивает значимость самих целей.

Можете посмотреть пример [отсюда](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452870/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85).

Answer (score 1):

**Правильно:**

***Мои цели на 2024-й*** (таковы): *найти по-немецки и -французски говорящих друзей, подарить Арине—Шерон подсолнечник и найти кота.*

Пояснительная конструкция, интонационное предупреждение.

**Сравнить:**

*Друг назвал фантастикой **мои цели на 2024-й** - найти по-немецки и -французски говорящих друзей, подарить Арине — Шерон подсолнечник и найти кота.*

Присоединительная конструкция.